# Kubernetes show secrets for namespace

Tags: kubernetes, documentation

I stumbled upon this command:

```
kubectl get secrets -n namespace-name
```

([Jay Beale, Attacking and Hardening Kubernetes | KringleCon 2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4ySed0k7uE&t=2m7s))

It seems to list the secrets for a specific namespace (here `namespace-name`). But I couldn't find any documentation about that (e.g. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/, https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get and googling it). Does anybody has some deeper insights about this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Searched at the wrong place:

`-n` is part of the core `kubectl` command:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/

> -n, --namespace string
> If present, the namespace scope for this CLI request

So it shows the results for a given namespace if applied.